# C# como fazer pesquisa em database usando parâmetros

Tags: c#, sql, algoritmo-de-busca, parâmetros

Tenho o seguinte código

```
public DataTable PesquisarPorNome(string NomePesquisado)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbEspecialidades WHERE NomeEspecialidade LIKE '%" + NomePesquisado + "%' ", conexao.StringConexao);
        adaptador.Fill(tabela);
        return tabela;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conexao.DesconectarDoBanco();
    }
}
```

Sei que se eu disponibilizar isso, a vaca vai para o brejo, pois SQL Injection está aí para isso, porém como usar parâmetros ?
Obrigado

Comment: Qual banco de dados vc esta usando?

Comment: Desculpe, não estou recebendo notificações, estou usando SQL

Comment: Antonio, o Structured Query Language  [(SQL)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)  é uma linguagem para consultar bancos de dados.

Comment: Ok, não sei se entendi a sua pergunta, estou usando o MSSQL  . Sei que SQL é uma linguagem , que muitas vezes confundimos com o MSSQL é que o SGBD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja o exemplo abaixo,

```
public DataTable PesquisarPorNome(string NomePesquisado)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = myConnString;
        try
        {
            var SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tbEspecialidades WHERE NomeEspecialidade  LIKE @NomePesquisado");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = SQL;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NomePesquisado", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + NomePesquisado + "%";
            SqlDataAdapter sqlA = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable tabela = new DataTable();

            sqlA.SelectCommand = cmd;

            conn.Open();
            sqlA.Fill(tabela);

            return tabela;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Só faltou vc especificar o banco de dados que esta usando..

Answer (score 3):

Assim que se faz consulta com parameters e LIKE clause.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbEspecialidades WHERE NomeEspecialidade LIKE '%'+ @NomePesquisado +'%'", connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NomePesquisado", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = NomePesquisado;
var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Quem deu downgrade pode justificar?