# Como ler dado do banco de dados MySQL de uma aplicação em c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Galera tenho uma tabela com 2 colunas no phpmyadmin,consigo conectar e ler uma coluna mas a outra não, da o seguinte erro

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Unknown column '(Nome que eu pesquiso)' in 'where clause'

```
 MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection(conex);
            MySqlCommand command = conectar.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT id from hackers where Nick= "+textBox1.Text;
        try{    
        conectar.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Conexão estabelecida!!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        { label1.Text = reader["nick"].ToString(); }
        conectar.Close();
    }
```

Quando uso SELECT NICK FROM HACKERS WHERE id=x funciona mas o contrario não

Comment: Tente usar parâmetros, `command.CommandText = "SELECT id from hackers where Nick = @Nick";`.

Comment: Meu palpite é que você esqueceu as aspa simples '' algo como  "SELECT id from hackers where Nick= '"+textBox1.Text+"'";

Comment: Cara a resposta é bem parecida com isso [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100752/c-como-fazer-pesquisa-em-database-usando-par%C3%A2metros/100763#100763)

Comment: Verifique como está a escrita a coluna **Nick**, pelo que vi no select está **NICK**, tente colocar assim.

Answer (score 2):

Duas coisas.

Primeiro, o erro ocorre por sintaxe. Se você vai buscar por strings, elas têm que ser cercadas por aspas simples.

Isso é errado:

```
... WHERE nick = x
```

Pois o banco considera que você quer comparar as colunas `nick` e `x` (e `x` não existe).

Isso é certo:

```
... WHERE nick = 'x'
```

O mais grave, porém, é que você monta o seu comando SQL através de concatenação. Se é apenas uma aplicação para aprender, isso não lhe fará mal agora. Mas se você liberar um sistema para a internet que faça buscas dessa forma, ele estará vulnerável a ataques. Então eu peço que após resolver o problema na sintaxe do comando, faça uma pesquisa (pode ser aqui no Stack Overflow mesmo) sobre **injeção de SQL**. Deixo a seu critério pesquisar e estudar isso no seu próprio tempo.

Answer (score 1):

Veja o exemplo abaixo...

```
public DataTable PesquisarPorNome(string NomePesquisado)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = myConnString;
        try
        {
            var SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tbEspecialidades WHERE NomeEspecialidade  LIKE @NomePesquisado");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = SQL;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NomePesquisado", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + NomePesquisado + "%";
            SqlDataAdapter sqlA = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable tabela = new DataTable();

            sqlA.SelectCommand = cmd;

            conn.Open();
            sqlA.Fill(tabela);

            return tabela;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Obs:** a conexão feita aqui é para o banco `sql server`, basta altera para o `mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

troque:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT id from hackers where Nick= "+textBox1.Text;
```

por

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT id from hackers where Nick like "+textBox1.Text;
```

Embora que eu recomendo usar Entity Framework, facilita muito o acesso ao banco de dados pois converte suas tabelas / registros em classes / objetos, facilitando assim o acesso e a manipulação dos mesmos.

Answer (score 0):

Se você deseja buscar mais de uma informação a instrução sql deveria ser

```
sqlCommand selectTable = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM nomeTabela WHERE nick = '@nick';", conexao);
```

e pra carregar os dados usar o laço da seguinte forma.

```
while(reader.Read())
    { 
       label1.Text = reader["nick"].ToString();
       label2.Text = reader["2ªColuna"].ToString(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```html
 command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT id from hackers where Nick='{0}'",textBox1.Text);
```